# detecting (exact) pupil diameter in python (and opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, detection

maybe someone can help me. I'm trying to get the (more or less) exact pupil diameter within a picture.

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv

img = cv2.imread('pupil_still_1.png',0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 100, 200)

cimg=cv2.cvtColor(edges, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges, cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10000, param1 = 50, param2 = 30, minRadius = 0, maxRadius = 0)

for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)

#Code to close Window
cv2.imshow('detected Edge',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
for i in range (1,5):
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

It's not a very complicated code and it is working quite well.

I'm sorry. I'd like to post two pictures but I've not enough reputation to do so. Therefore, I'll try to explane what is happening.

As you can see, I'm doing some image processing before I try to detect a circle. I can detect a cicle and it is also the pupil, but somehow it is not fitting well. The detected circle is much smaler.
It seems that HoughCircles detects a part of a smaler circle within the pupil.

I've no idea what I can do. Any suggestions what I can try?

Edit:
Picture to the original picture
https://oc.fk06.hm.edu/index.php/s/9Y6FExTQVFl04U4
(Not the best quality, but that's the challenge ;o) )

Picture to the transformed picture with HougheCircle detection
https://oc.fk06.hm.edu/index.php/s/tJk2WiSVPrMSLix

Comment: 1) Post at least a link to images, so we can see them. 2) Try to run houghCircles on "thresh", not "edges"

Comment: Doesn't HoughCircles want a Gray image?  Why convert to BGR?

Comment: @ stark Don't ask me. I was just following this tutorial 
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html
I think I saw this conversion in other examples here on Stackoverflow, too.

@ Miki When I'm trying "thresh" I get an error that it is not the right format. I'm sorry, currently I'm not at the right computer to post the correct error message. I can try to do this tomorrow if neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

its not working assertion failed and you didnt use harrcascades

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).